# Cocoapod compilation fails when loading .xib file

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I've pushed it to trunk. And then I did "pod install" to my own project, all files are downloaded (I can confirm it from Pods in my project). But it doesn't compile, it gives me this error

```
"Unable to run command 'StripNIB ABPhotoView.nib' - this target might include its own product."
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have found the solution. Follow below:

rather than adding a reference to the file in the s.source_files, I put it in the s.resources as shown below

s.resources = ["images/*.png", "classes/MyView.xib"]

For more details, https://github.com/bennyguitar/CollapseClick/issues/14

Answer (score 1):

It's crazy! Used to have the same issue when had such podspec string

> s.resources = "Project/**/*.{png,bundle,xib,nib}"

changing to

> s.resource = "Project/**/*.{png,bundle,xib,nib}"

has solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the syntax has evolved, maybe since the new Cocoapods version (1.0)

When you create your pod with the template described [here](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/making-a-cocoapod.html), your .podspec will contain some commented lines to include assets (like .png or .xib)

```
#  s.resource_bundles = {
#   'MyMarvelousComponent' => ['MyMarvelousComponent/Assets/*.png']
#  }
```

Just uncomment, change the .png with what you want to include, and move your files to Assets/ folder (because, this is the folder where they should be)

Note Cocoapods will automatically create a `.bundle` in the Products/ group, so if you need these assets in the example project, you'll need to select the right `NSBundle` first.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, when `podspec` file was incorrect. My mistake was that I didn't specify `.h` and `.m` extensions for `source_files`. Because of that `.xib` files were added twice. This is a correct example:

```
  s.source_files = 'YourTarget/Classes/**/*.{h,m}'

  s.resources = ['YourTarget/Classes/UIComponents/**/*.xib']
```

See https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#source_files